# Angular2: routerLink directive is not working (not redirecting)

Tags: angular, router

My routerlink seems to be fine yet it's not doing anything.
When I click the element it's not redirecting me at all.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="tile" routerLink="/risk-profiler/upload">
```

Comment: Add plz more details

Comment: It was a matter of missing import, I posted question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are importing the RouterModule:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [ RouterModule ]
  ...
})
```